# Javafxports android dex error

Tags: java, android, javafx, javafxports

Hi I'm trying to start using javafxports for build app for android,
I have android sdk and gradle (try with 2.3 & 2.2) for build simple app from getting start page of site but I get the error : What is the solution ?

```
Executing: gradle :android

SigningConfig{name=debug, storeFile=C:\Users\me\.android\debug.keystore, storePassword=android, keyAlias=AndroidDebugKey, keyPassword=android, storeType=C:\Users\me\.android\debug.keystore}
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileRetrolambdaMain UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:compileAndroidJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileRetrolambdaAndroid SKIPPED
:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileRetrolambdaTest SKIPPED
:compileRetrolambda UP-TO-DATE
:mergeClassesIntoJar
:validateManifest
:collectMultiDexComponents
:shrinkMultiDexComponents
:createMainDexList
[ant:java] Java Result: 1
:dex FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':dex'.
> org.gradle.api.GradleException (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 50.906 secs



Build failure (see the Notifications window for stacktrace): gradle :android
```

Stack trace:

```
Issue 1
--------

  Requested project: C:\Users\me\Documents\NetBeansProjects\jhg

  Stack trace:
    org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not execute build using Gradle installation 'C:\bin\gradle-2.2'.
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:57)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildLauncher.run(DefaultBuildLauncher.java:71)
        at org.netbeans.gradle.project.tasks.AsyncGradleTask.runBuild(AsyncGradleTask.java:313)
        at org.netbeans.gradle.project.tasks.AsyncGradleTask.doGradleTasksWithProgressIgnoreTaskDefCancel(AsyncGradleTask.java:410)
        at org.netbeans.gradle.project.tasks.AsyncGradleTask.doGradleTasksWithProgress(AsyncGradleTask.java:337)
        at org.netbeans.gradle.project.tasks.AsyncGradleTask.access$400(AsyncGradleTask.java:72)
        at org.netbeans.gradle.project.tasks.AsyncGradleTask$BuildExecutionItem$1.run(AsyncGradleTask.java:673)
        at org.netbeans.gradle.project.tasks.GradleDaemonManager.runBlockingGradleTask(GradleDaemonManager.java:52)
        at org.netbeans.gradle.project.tasks.GradleDaemonManager.access$200(GradleDaemonManager.java:23)
        at org.netbeans.gradle.project.tasks.GradleDaemonManager$2.execute(GradleDaemonManager.java:129)
        at org.jtrim.concurrent.AbstractTaskExecutorService$FunctionWrapper.execute(AbstractTaskExecutorService.java:270)
        at org.jtrim.concurrent.AbstractTaskExecutorService$TaskOfAbstractExecutor.execute(AbstractTaskExecutorService.java:340)
        at org.jtrim.concurrent.Tasks$RunOnceCancelableTask.execute(Tasks.java:342)
        at org.jtrim.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor$ThreadPoolTaskExecutorImpl$QueuedItem.runTask(ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.java:1213)
        at org.jtrim.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor$ThreadPoolTaskExecutorImpl$Worker.executeTask(ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.java:1046)
        at org.jtrim.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor$ThreadPoolTaskExecutorImpl$Worker.run(ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.java:1178)
        at org.jtrim.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor$ThreadPoolTaskExecutorImpl$Worker$1.run(ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.java:996)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Execution failed for task ':dex'.
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultExceptionAnalyser.transform(DefaultExceptionAnalyser.java:77)
        at org.gradle.initialization.MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.transform(MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.java:47)
        at org.gradle.initialization.StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.transform(StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.java:30)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:108)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildModelAction.run(BuildModelAction.java:43)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildModelAction.run(BuildModelAction.java:30)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ConfiguringBuildAction.run(ConfiguringBuildAction.java:119)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:47)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartStopIfBuildAndStop.execute(StartStopIfBuildAndStop.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:71)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:70)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonHygieneAction.execute(DaemonHygieneAction.java:39)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:46)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
    Caused by: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':dex'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:305)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:88)
        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:68)
        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
        ... 32 more
    Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: 
        at org.javafxports.jfxmobile.plugin.android.task.Dex.dex(Dex.groovy:45)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:63)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:218)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:211)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:200)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:579)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:562)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
        ... 55 more
```

Comment: Sir, can you please help me. I encountered the same problem like yours. Here's the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30473854/error-after-running-the-default-gluon-project-dex-failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found it, I download new oracle jdk 64 bit and istall it.

I think this error comes because I'm on 64 bit windows and use 32 bit jdk! with netbeans, after I remove 32 bit JDK & JRE I download 64 bit JDK from oracle site and install it and everything works good without any problem.