# Error after running the default Gluon project (: dex FAILED)

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, javafxports

I downloaded the Gluon plugin for Netbeans to deploy JavaFX application to Android. It ran successfully on the desktop but when I execute the `android` task, it throws an error:

```
Executing: gradle :android

:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileRetrolambdaMain UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:compileAndroidJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileRetrolambdaAndroid SKIPPED
:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileRetrolambdaTest SKIPPED
:compileRetrolambda UP-TO-DATE
:mergeClassesIntoJar
:validateManifest
:collectMultiDexComponents
:shrinkMultiDexComponents
:createMainDexList
[ant:java] Java Result: 1
:dex FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':dex'.
> org.gradle.api.GradleException (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 4 mins 29.297 secs
```

**Here's my software configuration:**

- I used JDK8u45 (I also set the path for JAVA_HOME)
- I used Netbeans 8.0.2 for the IDE
- I downloaded the Android SDK with API21 in it (I also set the path for ANDROID_HOME)
- I downloaded Gradle2.4 (I also set the path for GRADLE_HOME)
- I used `Windows XP` for the OS (32 bit)

**What could be the cause of that error?**

Here's the build.gradle:

```
 buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.0.0-b9'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

mainClassName = 'com.gluon.GlounMainApp'

jfxmobile {
    android {
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
    ios {
        infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
    }
}
```

Here's the stacktrace:

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task':dex'.
at      org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
at  org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:305)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:88)
at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:68)
at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:55)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:51)
at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionRep
ortingAction.java:33)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
at  org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.ja
va:30)
at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:127)
at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:58)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException:
at org.javafxports.jfxmobile.plugin.android.task.Dex.dex(Dex.groovy:45)
at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:63)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:218)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:211)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:200)
at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:579)
at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:562)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
at  org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
... 47 more
```

Here's the --debug output:

```
Finished executing task ':dex'
11:36:09.171 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.TaskExecutionLogger] :dex FAILED
11:36:09.187 [INFO]  [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] :dex (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 0.391 secs.
11:36:09.203 [DEBUG]  [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] Task worker  [Thread[main,5,main]] finished, busy: 1 mins 18.97 secs, idle: 0.421secs 11:36:09.265 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
11:36:09.265 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
11:36:09.281 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
11:36:09.296 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
11:36:09.312 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':dex'.
11:36:09.312 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] > org.gradle.api.Gradle
Exception (no error message)
11:36:09.328 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
11:36:09.343 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
11:36:09.343 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
11:36:09.359 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger]
11:36:09.375 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED
11:36:09.390 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger]
11:36:09.390 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] Total time: 2 mins 13.48
4 secs
11:36:09.406 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.daemon.CompilerDaemonManager                                                                       ]
                                                                           Stopping 0 compiler daemon(s).
11:36:09.421 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.daemon.CompilerDaemonManager                                                                        ]
                                                                           Stopped 0 compiler daemon(s).
11:36:09.421 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on buildscript class cache for build file  'C:\HelloGluon\build.gradle' (C:\gradle\caches\2.2.1\scripts\build_80spgxfpvahlvz1v3mywr9rd1\ProjectScript\buil
dscript).
11:36:09.437 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on no_buildscript class cache for build file 'C:\HelloGluon\build.gradle'
 (C:\gradle\caches\2.2.1\scripts\build_80spgxfpvahlvz1v3mywr9rd1\ProjectScript\no_buildscript).
11:36:09.453 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache                                                                            ]
                                                                           Closing cache fileHashes.bin (C:\HelloGluon\.gradle\2.2.1\taskArtifacts\fileHashe
s.bin)
11:36:09.453 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache                                                                             ]
                                                                           Closing cache fileSnapshots.bin (C:\HelloGluon\.gradle\2.2.1\taskArtifacts\fileSn
apshots.bin)
11:36:09.468 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache                                                                              ]
                                                                           Closing cache taskArtifacts.bin (C:\HelloGluon\.gradle\2.2.1\taskArtifacts\taskArtifacts.bin)
11:36:09.484 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache                                                                              ]
                                                                           Closing cache outputFileStates.bin (C:\HelloGluon\.gradle\2.2.1\taskArtifacts\outputFileStates.bin)
11:36:09.484 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on task history cache (C:\HelloGluon\.gradle\2.2.1\taskArtifacts).
11:36:09.500 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess] Cache Plugin
 Resolution Cache (C:\gradle\caches\2.2.1\plugin-resolution) was closed 0 times.

 11:36:09.500 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache                                                                              ]
                                                                           Closing cache artifact-at-repository.bin (C:\gradle\caches\modules-2\metadata-2.14\artifact-at-repository.bin)
11:36:09.515 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache                                                                              ]
                                                                           Closing cache module-metadata.bin (C:\gradle\caches\modules-2\metadata-2.14\module-metadata.bin)
11:36:09.531 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on artifact cache (C:\gradle\caches\modules-2).
 11:36:09.531 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.memcache.InMemoryCachedRepositoryFactory                                         ]
                                                                            In-memory dependency metadata cache closed. Repos cached: 4, cache instances: 1,modules served from cache: 0, artifacts: 0
11:36:09.546 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.    store.CachedStoreFactory                                                      ]
                                                                          Resolution result cache closed. Cache reads: 0, disk reads: 0 (avg: 0.0 secs, total: 0.0 secs)
 11:36:09.562 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.store.CachedStoreFactory                                                      ]
                                                                           Resolved configuration cache closed. Cache reads: 0, disk reads: 0 (avg: 0.0 secs, total: 0.0 secs)
11:36:09.562 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.store.ResolutionResultsStoreFactory                                           ]
                                                                            Deleted 2 resolution results binary files in 0.016 secs
```

Comment: @José Pereda, Sir, I used Gluon plugin, but still that error occured! What's wrong?

Comment: Does your JavaFX project has any external dependency?

Comment: @ItachiUchiha, No Sir, I dont have any external dependency. Its a fresh project created by Gluon Plugin.

Comment: @ItachiUchiha, Sir, what OS are you using? Is Windows XP supported?

Comment: Post the build.gradle file, and also try to run `gradlew --stacktrace android` from command line and post the stack trace.

Comment: You don't need to add the manifest line if you are not modifying the default AndroidManifest file

Comment: @JoséPereda The gluon plugin automatically generates the AndroidManifest.xml file which uses some default icons for the application.
@EthylCasin Could you try and run `gradlew --debug android`? It should print out the output from the actual dex command itself. That could give us more insight as to why the command fails.

Comment: @JoeriSykora I just meant the line added in the build.gradle file `manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'` was not necessary.

Comment: @JoséPereda, Sir, please see the debug output.

Comment: @JoeriSykora, Sir, please see the debug output.

Comment: You have only pasted the debug output after the dex command was finished, so the actual output from the dex command is missing in your paste. Could you please add the debug output that is printed before the first line that you have pasted now?

Comment: Running into the same problem with the HelloWorld demo app. I'm using vanilla gradle, so no IDE plugins.

Comment: @tbeernot @EthylCasin could you both provide the **full** output of the gradle command while specifying --debug: `./gradlew --debug android`. Thanks.

Comment: I already traced the error: the dex command per default sets an Xmx of 2g. Using 32 bit Java on 64 bit Windows 7 that fails. I added a dexOptions to the Android block in gradle.build to reduce that to 1024m.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same  problem now it's solved .Now I am able to  compile and make my android apk .

So these are the steps I followed

1. Make sure  you have updated your sdk manager -> support library
   to latest version (23.1.1)  it was the latest for me when I posted this
   answer.  This will update

> H:\sdk\extras\android\support\multidex  files

2. Make sure you add  your android sdk location in build.gradle 
   androidSdk='H:/ADT BUNDLE/sdk'

like this

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {

           classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.0.0-b9'


    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'


repositories {
    jcenter()
}

mainClassName = 'com.fff.Fff'

jfxmobile {
    android {
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
        androidSdk='H:/ADT BUNDLE/sdk'

    }
}
```

If you are working in a 32 bit PC

> Set environment variable name JAVA_OPTIONS with value  Xmx1024M

If you are working in a 64 bit PC

> make sure you install JDK that is 64 bit and not 32 bit JDK