# Error when compiling JavaFx to android using Gluon

Tags: java, android, javafx, netbeans, gluon

I have a Javafx application and I am trying to port to android using the gluon plugin for netbeans. I am currently getting this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':createMainDexList'.

  > Exception in thread "main" com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: InvokeDynamic not supported
  >   at com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.determineOffsets(ConstantPoolParser.java:226)
  >   at com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.parse(ConstantPoolParser.java:132)
  >   at com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.parseIfNecessary(ConstantPoolParser.java:124)
  >   at com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.getPool(ConstantPoolParser.java:115)
  >   at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:491)
  >   at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
  >   at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToEndIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:397)
  >   at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getAttributes(DirectClassFile.java:311)
  >   at com.android.multidex.MainDexListBuilder.hasRuntimeVisibleAnnotation(MainDexListBuilder.java:191)
  >   at com.android.multidex.MainDexListBuilder.keepAnnotated(MainDexListBuilder.java:167)
  >   at com.android.multidex.MainDexListBuilder.(MainDexListBuilder.java:121)
  >   at com.android.multidex.MainDexListBuilder.main(MainDexListBuilder.java:91)
  >   at com.android.multidex.ClassReferenceListBuilder.main(ClassReferenceListBuilder.java:58)
  >   ...while preparsing cst 000e at offset 00000047
  >   ...while parsing de/jensd/fx/glyphs/control/skin/GlyphCheckBoxSkin.class
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

I have the jdk 8 (64bit) running and this is my build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.0.9'
}
}
apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
jcenter()
maven {
    url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
}
 }

mainClassName = 'com.mypackage.MyMainClass'
ext.CHARM_DOWN_VERSION = "1.0.0"

dependencies {
compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:3.0.0'

compile 'com.jfoenix:jfoenix:1.6.0'
compile 'de.jensd:fontawesomefx-emojione:2.2.7-2'
compile 'de.jensd:fontawesomefx-fontawesome:4.7.0-5'
compile 'de.jensd:fontawesomefx-icons525:3.0.0-4'
compile 'de.jensd:fontawesomefx-materialdesignfont:1.7.22-4'
compile 'de.jensd:fontawesomefx-materialicons:2.2.0-5'
compile 'de.jensd:fontawesomefx-octicons:4.3.0-5'
compile 'de.jensd:fontawesomefx-weathericons:2.0.10-5'
compile 'de.jensd:fontawesomefx-controls:8.15'
compile 'org.controlsfx:controlsfx:8.40.11'

compile 'org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.8.6'

compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20090211'

runtime files('lang')


androidRuntime 'com.gluonhq:charm-android:3.0.0'
iosRuntime 'com.gluonhq:charm-ios:3.0.0'
desktopRuntime 'com.gluonhq:charm-desktop:3.0.0'

compile "com.gluonhq:charm-down-common:$CHARM_DOWN_VERSION"
desktopRuntime "com.gluonhq:charm-down-desktop:$CHARM_DOWN_VERSION"
androidRuntime "com.gluonhq:charm-down-android:$CHARM_DOWN_VERSION"
iosRuntime "com.gluonhq:charm-down-ios:$CHARM_DOWN_VERSION"
}

jfxmobile {
android {
    manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
    androidSdk='C:\\AndroidSDK'
}
ios {
    infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
    forceLinkClasses = [
            'com.gluonhq.**.*',
            'io.datafx.**.*',
            'javax.annotations.**.*',
            'javax.inject.**.*',
            'javax.json.**.*',
            'org.glassfish.json.**.*'
    ]
}
}
```

Please help!

I have the 64bit of jdk8 running and not 32bit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Build failure for JavaFX android app using the gluon mobile plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42012132/build-failure-for-javafx-android-app-using-the-gluon-mobile-plugin)

Comment: I have read the post, I have the 64bit of jdk8 running so that isn't the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my gluon classpath from

```
classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.0.9'
```

To
    classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.3.3'

And I was able to build the apk.